# The structure of a mobile app with Qt Quick Controls

Tags: android, qt, qt-quick, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

In the old days of `com.nokia.meego` or even now with the `Sailfish.Silica` module you are using the "Pages" for navigation inside the app.

What should be used instead when developing a mobile app for Android with the Qt Quick Controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your needs, I'd say for basic apps a simple `TabView` will suffice, for more complex dialog design you will probably need a `StackView`.

Naturally, you can also nest one into the other.

Lastly, with QML it is easy enough to implement your custom app navigation system using dynamic object instantiation, animations and effects.

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be split into two: a design question and an implementation question.

The former can be rephrased as "what structure should my mobile app targeted to Android have?" whereas the latter can be rephrased as "what does QtQuick give me to implement that structure?"

As for the first question, there is a [very rich section](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#) in the "Material Design" specs which deals with app and navigation structure. You should consider those recommendations in the light of your specific use case and similar examples that you can find. Also, take a good look at [QML Material](https://github.com/papyros/qml-material), as that gives you an almost direct mapping to implement your Android-targeted (or even cross-platform) design with a set of ready-made Material components.

Once you have defined the design question, the choice of QtQuick components for implementation falls more or less naturally, and you have the options that @ddriver mentioned above, and even more.